# Correct syntax for VBScritp for using regex.replace with RegexOptions.Singleline

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript

I have been unable to get correct syntax for VBScript in using regex replace with `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Goal is to extract some text from strSearchString and using back references to hold extracted data I want with  $1=abc-123 and $2=122 $3=133 $4=144 $5=155

I can get the regex pattern to work on various RegEx online testers using the singleline option, but
 unsure on correct syntax for VBScript and I get a pop-up error on various things I have tried.

```
Error:  Object required: ' RegexOptions'
Code: 800A01A8
```

Here is my code:

```
Set objRegEx = New RegExp

objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.Pattern ="(\S+)\r\n.+\040ip\040address\040(\d+)\056(\d+)\056(\d+)\056(\d+)"

strSearchString = "abc-123" + vbCrlf + " Company Name Street Address" + vbCrlf + " ip address 122.133.144.155"

Wscript.Echo strSearchString

strExtract = objRegEx.Replace(strSearchString, objRegEx.Pattern, "test $1 $2 $3 $4 $5", RegexOptions.Singleline)

Wscript.Echo strExtract
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vbscript not support singleline mode but you can try this pattern:

```
(\S+)[\s\S]*ip\saddress\s(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
```